# Scatterplot with Two Regression Lines

Tags: descriptive-statistics

In a scatterplot, let K denote the least-squares regression line computed with outlier A included and let L denote the least-squares regression line computed without outlier A.  Which of the following must be true about the slopes of K and L?

a) Both slopes are positive, and the slope of K is less than the slope of L.
b) Both slopes are positive, and the slope of K is greater than the slope of L.
c) The slope of K is negative, and the slope of L is positive.
d) The two slopes are equal.

I encountered this statistics problem in a recent test and though I have already taken statistics 1 I was not familiar with this problem.  I guessed choice a and I wonder if that is the correct answer.  Those any one knows the answer to this problem.  Thank you.

Comment: I encountered the problem in a recent test not text.

Comment: Does the question also include the scatterplot?

Comment: Insufficient information. Any of those 3 statements could be true - for different scatter plots.